HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=#####): Read timed out. (read timeout=120) with undetected_chromedriver
I am currently writing a program in python which creates a web bot using the undetected_chromedriver library:
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import undetected_chromedriver

driver_options = Options()
driver_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, user_multi_procs=True, headless=False, options=driver_options)

However, during running of this web bot for a certain amount of time I receive the error:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=#####): Read timed out. (read timeout=120)HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=51220): Read timed out. (read timeout=120)

What is the reason for this error?

(sorry I accidentally pasted the error twice)
